# Maonites, Midianites or are they the same?

Tags: judges

In Judges 10:12 (NASB)

> And when the Sidonians, the Amalekites, and the **Maonites** oppressed you, you cried out to Me, and I saved you from their hands.

I've checked [other versions](https://biblehub.com/judges/10-12.htm) and some reference Midianites instead of Maonites.

Also, [Jamieson-Fausset-Brown Bible Commentary](https://biblehub.com/commentaries/judges/10-12.htm) mentions

> Maonites—that is, "Midianites."

In this passage, is it Maonites, Midianites or are they the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Maon* occurs 8 times in the OT with three different meanings:

1. A town of Judah, Josh 15:55, 1 Sam 25:2, 23:34, 25:1
2. The name of a man, 1 Chron 2:45
3. The name of a people, Judges 10:12, 1 Chron 4:41.

In Judges 10:12, the LXX translates this word as Μαδιάμ, ie, the *Midianites*, hence the comment of Jamieson-Fausset-Brown Bible Commentary.  The Cambridge and Ellicott commentary observes the same thing but this does not make the Hebrew text wrong as the LXX is known to take liberties with the Hebrew text at times as both these note.

However, Moanites may well be the intended and correct word here as Matthew Poole observes, there are several possibilities:

> Maonites; either, **first**, Those who lived in or near the wilderness
> of Maon, in the south of Judah, 1 Samuel 23:25 25:2, whether Edomites
> or other. Or, **secondly**, The Mehunims, a people living near the
> Arabians, of whom 2 Chronicles 26:7. For in the Hebrew the letters of
> both names are the same, only the one is the singular, the other the
> plural number. Or, **thirdly**, The Midianites, whose oppression he
> would not omit; it being usual for one and the same person or persons
> to have two names; although the Midianites may be comprehended under
> the Amalekites, with whom they were joined, Judges 6:3,33. Or,
> **fourthly**, Some other people now unknown, and not expressed elsewhere in Scripture.

In the absence of clear information of Scripture, I am inclined to leave the Hebrew text as it is and accept the Moan and Moanites is what is intended.

Comment: Happy to see your answer, specially after the incident yesterday in the other question. That was on my mind and prayers throughout the day today and happy it ended this way. God bless you.

Comment: @TiagoMartinsPeres李大仁 - I am honored to be of some service.  God bless you.